# I need to call a Javascript function on click of my <a> tag in my web page to show and hide <div> content

Tags: javascript, html

I have attached the java Script file in body section of the page but its still not working.

```js
Here is #javascript function that i want to call

function opentab(evt, tab) {
var i, content, links;
    content = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
    for(i = 0;i < content.length;i++){
        content[i].display="none";
    }
    links=document.getElementsByClassName("linked");
    for(i=0; i < links.length;i++){
        links[i].className=links[i].className.replace("active", "");
   
    }
    
    window.document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
This is the #HTML code i want to call the above method onclick of <a> tag to show the specific div. 

    <div class="sidebar">
        <img src="PNG%20WE%20Carry%20Fast-01.png" alt="Logo">
                          
        <a href="#" onclick='opentab(event, 'home')'  class="linked"  ><i class="fas fa-home" ></i>
          Home                </a>
      <a href="#" onclick='opentab(event, 'routes')'    class="linked" >
          <i class="fas  fa-route"></i> Routes</a>
      <a href="#" onclick='opentab(event, 'vehicles')'    class="linked" ><i class="fas fa-truck-moving"></i>
          Vehicles</a>
      <a href="#" onclick='opentab(event, 'QRcode')'    class="linked" ><i class="fas fa-qrcode"></i> Qr Code</a>
        
      <a href="#" onclick='opentab(event, 'OrderStatus')'     class="linked" ><i class="fas fa-box"></i> Order Status</a>
      <a href="#" onclick='opentab(event, 'Report')'   class="linked" ><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
          Report</a>         
        </div>
   
      <div id="home" class="main">
        <h1>Hi welcome to your home page
        </h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you share code snippet here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `onclick='opentab(event, 'OrderStatus')'` would not execute because of incorrectly nested quotes. Try `onclick="opentab(event, 'OrderStatus')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick='opentab(event, 'OrderStatus')'` would not execute because of incorrectly nested quotes.

Try `onclick="opentab(event, 'OrderStatus')"`

so that the inside quotes `''` are not in conflict with the outside double quotes `""`

Also there is no display property associated with a division. What you are trying to achieve is to set the style property.

```
content[i].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: but it still doesn't hide the div its still showing all the divs.

Comment: anybody else there